# Find numbers that fit each riddle look for more than one answer

Tags: problem-solving

There are two $2$ digits numbers. The first number is greater than $50$ and ends in $0$. When you subtract one number from the other number the difference is $29$

Comment: What have you tried? The question will likely be closed if you have no effort of your own to offer

Comment: Is that the whole riddle? There would be an infinite pair of numbers to choose from if that's the whole criteria that we have to pick from.

Comment: @Aldon The numbers only have two digits.

Comment: @Théophile Oh must've missed that part, sorry it's 3 in the morning here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try something like $x-y = 29$ where $x = 10n, n \in \{6,7,8,9\}$

Comment: or $y - x = 29$. It is not clear from the wording that the "2nd number" is always the one being subtracted.

Comment: True, but this is just a starting point for OP

Comment: This does not cover all solutions.

Comment: More practically, one of the numbers is 60, 70, 80, or 90 so the other is any of those $\pm$ 29.  Eight possibilities but two of them involve numbers greater than 100.

Comment: Again, this is just a starting point for OP.

Answer (score -1):

$|a0 - bc| = 29$.  $a0 > 50.$

Case 1: $a0 > bc$

so $a0 - bc = 10a - (10b + c) = 10(a - b) - c = 29 \implies c = 1; a-b = 3$.  Possibilities: $(a0, [a-3]1) =\{(60, 31)(70,41)(80,51)(90,61)\}$.

Case 2: $bc > a0$

so $bc - a0 = 10b + c - 10a = 10(b-a) + c = 29 \implies c = 9; b- a = 2$.
Possibilities:$ ([a+2]9, a0) = \{(89,60)(99,70)\}$

=====

Or if you don't like algebra.

One number is a=  60, 70, 80, or 90 and the other is $a \pm 29$.  There are 8 possibilities but two of them are impossible.

Comment: Formatting...?!

Comment: What about formatting?  Formatting adds nothing in this case and doesn't make anything easier to read.

Comment: The lack of formatting here actually does make it very painful to read.

Comment: Because it's not in italics?

Comment: The ease of reading something that is in italics (which is all formatting adds in this case) vs. something that isn't in italics is utterly subjective.  The difficulty in typing with formatting is exponentially more difficult.

Comment: Okay, now it is formatted.  You can't honestly claim that is one iota easier and less painful to read, can you?  I can sure as f@@@ tell you it was a *LOT* more painful to type though.

Comment: Also you should give meaning to the symbols you use, for instance $bc$ could mean $b\times c$.

Comment: Could you tone down your attitude a bit? There's no reason to be so obnoxious here. As for formatting, it isn't just about italics. As Daniel just pointed out, there's the matter of explaining what you're doing. To give one example of confusing formatting, in the first line, you've written $29.a0$, and the reader has to figure out, among other things, that there should be a space after the period and that $a0$ means $10a + 0$.

Comment: There *was* a space after the period.  It's disappeared *because* I added latex.  In this case latex makes things *harder*.

Comment: @fleablood I think you have a valid point, but consider that it's your effort balanced against that iota * the number of people who will ever read this answer.